# Search string and replace with prefix in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like browse file with NodeJS and add prefix to each `*.png`/`.webm` string.

For example :

`hello-guys.png` => `/custom/path/to/hello-guys.png`.

I've try with [this package](https://github.com/adamreisnz/replace-in-file), but can't add prefix :

```
const options = {
  files: path.join(__dirname, '../data.js'),
  from: [
    /.png/g,
    /.webm/g
  ],
  // to: ['bar', 'bax']
  to: ['foo', 'bar']
};

replace(options)
  .then(changes => {
    console.log('Modified files:', changes.join(', '));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  });
```

Anyone know help me ?

Thank you community :)

Comment: You have to show your code and effort you made to answer the question (including some code of yours). In your question you ask to change filename (path), but the package you referenced change file content.

Comment: *"...but can't add prefix..."* You'll need to do more debugging (or just tell us more about what debugging you've done). Is it not matching the files? Not making the replacements? Getting the replacements wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's my problem. I've try to test with `readFile` but my file don't have always same structure, so i can't loop my array for replace my string

Comment: Also, what do the lines in the file look like? How can you tell where a path *begins*, for instance?

Comment: I don't have access to my file. the content his array of array of array :(

Comment: You surely can provide an example of the file contents (or what you expect them to be). You can't code in a vacuum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to insert a prefix before the path leading up to the file extension, your search regexes can't just be `.ext`, you need to specify something that will match the entire path. For instance, **if** these paths start at the beginning of a line:

```
from: [/^.+\.png/g, /^.+\.webm/g]
```

Or if they don't start at the beginning of a line, but they're separated from what comes before them with whitespace, then:

```
from: [/[^\s]+\.png/g, /[^\s]+\.webm/g]
```

Either way, then based on the documentation of the package, you'll need to specify a callback as `to` rather than a static string:

```
to: match => "/custom/path/to/" + match
```

Comment: Thank you @crowder ! I've edited my regex with this, and it work nice `/([a-z0-9\/_-]+\.(png|webm))/ig`